# Unable to kill a process when executing jar file using taskkill

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, pid

I have an `exe` triggered from within a java swing application. I  am able to kill the `exe` using `"taskkill /PID ProcessID "` when running the application from ECLIPSE IDE . But when i try to run the `jar file` for the swing application through a batch file, the `exe` doesn't get terminated probably because I am unable to obtain the process ID. I am using windows XP 32 bit. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
String sDosCommand = "cmd /c tasklist /FI " + "\"" + "IMAGENAME eq " + sProcessName + "\"" ;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sDosCommand );
```

This code (modified to get `process ID` of one particular process) gives me the `Process ID`, which in turn I use in `Taskkill` command executed similarly

Thanks and regards
Arun Raj

Comment: post the code that you have tried

Comment: String sDosCommand = "cmd /c tasklist /FI " + "\""   + "IMAGENAME eq " + sProcessName + "\"" ;Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sDosCommand ); this code (modified to get process ID of one particular process) gives me the process ID , which inturn I use in Taskkill command executed similarly

Comment: i think `GuillaumePolet` has given a good example and i also tried that way before. anyway post your complete code. i think there should be some path related issues

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to start your external application. If you are not, consider using that class and its `start()` method to launch the external application, as explained in the Javadoc.

Once you have called `start()`, you will get a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), on which you can call `destroy()` to kill the external application.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
...
p.destroy(); // this kills the command "myCommand"
```

Comment: @arunraj Ok, this is the "old" way of doing things in Java but it is pretty much as valid. The returned `Process` is of the same type as the one returned by `ProcessBuilder.start()`, so the rest of the answer is also valid for that case. Simply call `destroy` on `process` to stop/kill the process.

Comment: I have tried this.But destroying the process doesn't stop the exe that was spawned from it.The thread is getting stopped but my exe continues to run.And to add, I am trigerring a batch file from the process which in turn triggers the required exe

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where the problem was.I was triggering the application jar from a batch file . This batch was also modifying the environment varibles(PATH to be precise) which was preventing me from executing the TASKKILL command  . I have made a slight modification to the batch file to include the PATH environment variable as well.This solves my problem.

Thanks to all for their help.
Arun Raj